# CancelEdit and EndEdit for Inline Editing is not working all times

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` control and I am showing list of users on it. The `DataGridView` is bound with `DataTable` which is populated using ADO.net. I am using `DataGridViewLinkColumn` to enable Inline editing of a complete row and everything is working like a charm. There are two `DataGridViewLinkColumn`. One has text "Edit" and the other has value "Cancel". When I call `CancelEdit` and `EndEdit` when user click on Cancel then `DataGridView` row is rolled back to its original value. I want the same functionality to be performed when user click on "Edit" button for any other row. When "Edit" is clicked for any other row then it work just like as User has clicked Cancel and it makes the Row again ReadOnly but it is not rolling back to the original values. Below is my code,

```
Private Sub dgvDDMUsers_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvDDMUsers.CellContentClick

    Try

        Dim senderGrid As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If TypeOf senderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewLinkColumn AndAlso
           e.RowIndex >= 0 Then

            If senderGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = "Edit" Then

                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In senderGrid.Rows

                    If row.Index = e.RowIndex Then
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        row.ReadOnly = False

                        row.Cells(dgvDDMUsers.Columns("Edit").Index).Value = "Save"
                        row.Cells(dgvDDMUsers.Columns("Cancel").Index).Value = "Cancel"
                    Else
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
                        row.ReadOnly = True

                        row.Cells(dgvDDMUsers.Columns("Edit").Index).Value = "Edit"
                        row.Cells(dgvDDMUsers.Columns("Cancel").Index).Value = "            "
                    End If

                Next

            ElseIf senderGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = "Save" Then

                '' Code for Updating the Row values will come here

            ElseIf senderGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = "Cancel" Then

                senderGrid.CancelEdit()
                senderGrid.EndEdit()

                senderGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
                senderGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).ReadOnly = True

                senderGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(dgvDDMUsers.Columns("Edit").Index).Value = "Edit"
                senderGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(dgvDDMUsers.Columns("Cancel").Index).Value = "            "

            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

I have tried calling `senderGrid.CancelEdit()` and `senderGrid.EndEdit()` inside "Edit" click block but it is not working. What I am missing here. Why it is working inside block where "Cancel" click is captured but inside code block where "Edit" click is captured.

Comment: Why are you calling `EndEdit` at all when the user clicks 'Cancel'?  That's pointless given that you have called `CancelEdit` immediately before but potentially bad because it's purpose is to commit any pending changes.

Comment: As for the issue, it seems to me that you should be calling `CancelEdit` first when the user clicks 'Edit', which you're not doing in that code.  If the first thing you want to do is cancel a pending edit then that's what you need to do before you then begin the new edit.